# Can all possible values of this inequality occur?

Tags: real-analysis

Recall the inequality lim inf $x$ $+$ lim inf $y$ $\leq$ lim inf $(x+y)$ $\leq$ lim sup $(x+y)$ $\leq$  lim sup $x$ $+$ lim sup $y$. By replacing the inequality signs with some equality and/or strict inequality signs, we get 8 possible combinations of statements. Can all these 8 possibilities occur, and if so can anyone give me 8 pairs of sequences for each of the possibilities.

Comment: Can you produce at least one of the eight examples you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $x$ and $y$ are sequences.

If $x=y$ then you get an equality in everything. It is left to construct $x$ and $y$ with an inequality for each. For this consider $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n = (-1)^{n+1}$.

Then $\liminf x_n = -1= \liminf y_n = -1$, $x+y=0$ and $\limsup x_n = \limsup y_n = 1$.

We get $-2<0=0<2$.

It is left to find $x,y$ which satisfy

$\liminf (x+y)< \limsup (x+y)$

for this we can take $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=0$.